# help with improper integral claim

Tags: calculus, functions, improper-integrals

We are finding difficulties in solving this claim:

> Let's suppose that
>   $$
> \int_a^\infty f(x)^2 dx < \infty \text{ and }
> \int_a^\infty f''(x)^2 dx < \infty.
> $$
>   Prove that $$\int_a^\infty f'(x)^2 dx < \infty.$$

Thank everyone who can solve this claim or give any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: integration by parts and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: we already did it but there is an limit of f(x)*f'(x) after doing integration by parts 
and how do you proof that this limit exists at all
by the way...thank you for the quick response

Comment: Following this good suggestion by @Robert Israel you see that $\int_a^x (f'(t))^2 \, dt = f(x)f'(x) - f(a)f'(a) - \int_a^x f(t)f''(t) \, dt$.  The integral on the RHS must converge (Cauchy-Schwarz) and since the integrand on the LHS is non-negative, the limit exists -- either finite or $+\infty$.But we can't have $f(x)f'(x) \to +\infty$ because $2(f^2(x) - f^2(a)) = \int_a^x f(t)f'(t) \, dt$ and $f^2(x) \to +\infty$ contradicts given that $f^2$ is integrable.